# Pass API into an array

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass the data from methods into my empty array rows ,how i can easly pass it or how to call the API into rows

```
 export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data: {
        headers: [
          { title: 'id', key: 'id' },
          { title: 'name', key: 'name' },
          { title: 'city', key: 'city' },
          { title: 'address', key: 'address' }
        ],
        rows: []

      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    BaseTable
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUsers () {
      this.$axios.get('https://605c40b36d85de00170d9a8f.mockapi.io/user/zurich')
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.tableData = data
          console.log(data)
        })
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the response from your api arrives, you just have to add to your property declared in the method data.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      row: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetching() {
      fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          
          this.row = res.results; //Results added into array
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="fetching">Fetch Api</button>
  
  <div v-for="(item, key) in row" :key="key" style="margin: 2rem auto;" >
    <p>- {{ item.id }} | {{ item.name }} | {{ item.status }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```